# Flask: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

In my Flask backend, I receive a dict that gets processed and added to different dicts.

```
    def updateIncomeExpenses(self, incomingUpdate):
        '''
        The list of dicts are iterated over, and dicts are added to their respective lists.
            Parameter:
            incomingUpdate (list): A list of dictionaries with entries that are either incomes or expenses
        '''
        self.__latestUpdate = incomingUpdate

        for item in self.__latestUpdate:
            item = {key:val for key,val in item.items() if val != None}
            if item.get("incomes"):
                item["incomes"] = float(item.get("incomes"))
                self.__incomes[item.get("id")] = item
                self.__incomes["summary"] += item.get("incomes")
            elif item.get("expenses"):
                item["expenses"] = float(item.get("expenses"))
                self.__expenses[item.get("id")] = item
                self.__expenses["summary"] += item.get("expenses")
            elif item.get("savings"):
                item["savings"] = float(item.get("savings"))
                self.__savings[item.get("id")] = item
                self.__savings["summary"] += item.get("savings")
            elif item.get("investments"):
                item["investments"] = float(item.get("investments"))
                self.__investments[item.get("id")] = item
                self.__investments["summary"] += item.get("investments")
```

Even as I don't do any comparisons, the following error is thrown, and the traceback is not helping me find it.

Error: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1969, in finalize_request
    response = self.process_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2268, in process_response
    self.session_interface.save_session(self, ctx.session, response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/sessions.py", line 378, in save_session
    val = self.get_signing_serializer(app).dumps(dict(session))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/itsdangerous/serializer.py", line 207, in dumps
    payload = want_bytes(self.dump_payload(obj))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/itsdangerous/url_safe.py", line 53, in dump_payload
    json = super().dump_payload(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/itsdangerous/serializer.py", line 169, in dump_payload
    return want_bytes(self.serializer.dumps(obj, **self.serializer_kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/json/tag.py", line 305, in dumps
    return dumps(self.tag(value), separators=(",", ":"))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/json/__init__.py", line 211, in dumps
    rv = _json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 234, in dumps
    return cls(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

This has me so confused, and would love if anyone has an idea as to what this might be.

Comment: It looks like the error is happening while it is trying to save the session.  What have you stored in your session?  Have you possibly used integers as keys in your session?

Comment: What makes you think the error is happening in that function?

Comment: @JohnGordon basically, when I remove that code the error does not appear and generally I'm not using any sort of comparison throughout my code.

Comment: @TimRoberts it could be actually, because the ID is read from the DB as an integer

Comment: If you're using the ID as a key in the session (as opposed to a value), then you should convert it to a string first.  JSON can't handle integer keys.

Comment: @TimRoberts Awesome I learned something new! It woks now - the issue was that I was saving integers as keys

Answer (score 0):

What fixed it for me was that I accidentally had a key that was a `bool` type instead of a string. This seems to cause the issue.

If you have something like:

```
question="why do I exist?"
is_answered=False
data={
    question:question,
    is_answered:is_answered,
}
jsonify(data)
```

you need to change it to:

```
question="why do I exist?"
is_answered=False
data={
    "question":question,
    "is_answered":is_answered,
}
jsonify(data)
```

If the data were just `data={question:question}` then no error would be thrown, but your key would not be what you think it is!

Comment: Did you mean `value = "True"`?

Comment: @chepner no. A value (in this case, `value2`) can be `True` in python which becomes `true` (not `"true"`) in json. In most cases, you do not want string `"true"` when you actually want boolean `true`.

Comment: I realize that; my point is that nothing changed from the first code block to the second. When you say "I accidentally had a key that was a `bool` type", I assume you wanted to change `value2=True` to `value2="True"`.

Comment: I've edited the example to be a bit simpler and more representative of what issue I actually encountered. I hope its clearer what went wrong.